# websocket send parameter in connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I need to create a very simple text chat using `nodejs` and `Websocket`.

I have everything set up and working.

I now need to allow users to send a parameter in the websocket `connection` URL.

Like so: `websocket = new WebSocket("ws://test-website.net:8080/?id=55");`

in my reserach I came across quite a few similar questions and found out that I can pass the parameters in the URL like the example above.

However, none of them mentions or explains how to get this parameter (*55 in this example*) in `server.js`

```
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {

///I need to get the parameter here////

});
```

Any advice on this issue?

Comment: Which websocket server-side library are you using?

Comment: @ouni, I have mentioned that in my question. I am using node js.

Comment: Node has multiple websocket implementations, such as `ws` and `websocket`... (they are not in core) which one are you using?  The `require` statement will tell you.

Comment: @ouni, I am using WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your websocket request handler, it is normally passed the web socket as the first argument; the incoming HTTP request is passed as a **second** argument:

```
webSocketServer.on('connection', function connection(ws_client_stream, incoming_request) {
  console.log(incoming_request.url);
});
```

From there, you can use `url.parse` to get the components of the URL, such as the query string that you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

For websocket library in nodejs [(websocket.js npm)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket) :

```
wsServer.on('request', function(request){
    var FullURL = request.resourceURL.query;
    console.log(FullURL);
    // . . your code  . . //
}
```

link = wss://localhost/?param=value
**output**

```
{ param : 'value' }
```

here request.resourceURL retuen a object

```
Url {
  protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: '?id=65&encoding=text',
  query: { id: '65', encoding: 'text' },
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/?id=65&encoding=text',
  href: '/?id=65&encoding=text' }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 'websocket' lib, the following code retrieves your queryStrings:

```
wsServer.on('request', function(request) 
{
    console.log(request.resourceURL.query);
}
```

Note 1: You don't need to parse anything here.

Note 2: Though it has been answered years ago, this answer goes to those in case where people find the above-mentioned answer more complicated.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'resourceURL' of undefined